# How to find eclipse cdt version?

Tags: eclipse

how do I find the eclipse cdt version that I am using ? I went through eclipse.ini file but could not find out the cdt vesion number. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Open 'Help > Installation Details' and look at the Installed Software tab. This shows the versions of everything that is installed.